# Reaction of diamines with carboxylic acids to form imidazole

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, amines, heterocyclic-compounds, amides

I've recently came across this reaction and my guess is that firstly an amide forms that later reacts with the second amine group. Is this a general reaction? Does it matter if the compounds used are aromatic?

[image: Reaction between benzene‐1,2‐diamine and picolinic acid yielding in 2‐(pyridin‐2‐yl)‐1H‐1,3‐benzodiazole]

Comment: This is a general reaction of diamines, aromatic or otherwise, and carboxylate groups - whether acid, esters or amides. Uusally needs high temperatures and long reaction times to give a decent yield. Good candidate for being done in a microwave reactor.